# A characterisation of semi-continuity

Tags: analysis, functions, continuity

> Show that function $J$ is semi-continuous at point $v\in U$ iff $\forall \epsilon >0$ there exists $\delta >0$ such that $\forall u\in U\cap L_\delta (v)$, $J(u)>J(v)-\epsilon $.

$L_\delta (v)$ is open ball with center in $v$ and radius $\delta$.

Definition of semi-continuity is "Function $J: U\rightarrow R, U\subset R^n$ is semi-continuous from under at point $v\in U$ if $\lim\limits_{k \to \infty} \inf J(u_k)\geq J(v)$ for every sequence $\{u_k\}_{k\in N}$ that converges to $v$".

Please, can anyone help me to show this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**"If" part:** Suppose that the "$\varepsilon/\delta$" condition holds, and let $u_k$ be a sequence as in definition of semicontinuity. Fix $\varepsilon$, and take $\delta$ as in the condition. Then for some $n_0$, for $k > n_0$ we have $u_k \in L_\delta(u)$. Hence $J(u_k) > J(v) - \varepsilon$. Passing to $\liminf_k J(u_k) \geq J(v) - \varepsilon$. Since $\varepsilon > 0$ was arbitrary, you get $\liminf_k J(u_k) \geq J(v)$

**"Only if" part:** 
 Suppose that $J$ is semicontinuous from below. If the "$\varepsilon/\delta$" condition was false, then for some $\varepsilon > 0$ we would be able to find $u_k$ with $|u_k - v| < \frac{1}{k}$ but $J(u_k) \leq J(v) - \varepsilon$ (else, $\delta = 1/k$ would work). Passing to the limit we find $\liminf_k J(u_k) \leq J(v) - \varepsilon$, contradicting semicontinuity.

Comment: Why did you write that $u_k\in L_\delta (u)$ if, by definition, $\lim \{u_k\} = v$ not $\lim \{u_k\} = u$?